# Character being skipped when looping through string

Tags: python, python-3.x, lexer

I'm making a hobby programming language and there's an issue with my lexer when its reading an integer.

Here is the code for when the current character is in a string list of numbers:

```py
integers = "1234567890"
```

```py
elif currentChar in integers:
                res = ""

                while pos < length and src[pos] in integers:
                    print(src[pos])
                    res += src[pos]

                    pos += 1
                    column += 1
                
                pos += 1
                column += 1
                tokens.append({"type": "INTEGER", "value": res})
```

If you need the entire main lexer function here it is:

```py
def tokenize(self):
        tokens = []
        
        pos = 0
        line = 1
        column = 1

        src = self.src

        length = len(src)

        varChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_"
        integers = "1234567890"

        KEYWORDS = ["print"]

        while pos < length:
            currentChar = src[pos]

            if currentChar == " ":
                pos += 1
                column += 1
                continue
            elif currentChar == "\n":
                line += 1
                column = 0
                pos += 1
                continue
            elif currentChar == '"':
                pos += 1
                column += 1

                res = ""

                while pos < length and src[pos] != '"':
                    res += src[pos]

                    pos += 1
                    column += 1

                try:
                    if src[pos] != '"':
                        return [], f"Unterminated string at line {line}, column {column}"
                except IndexError:
                    if src[pos - 1] != '"':
                        return [], f"Unterminated string at line {line}, column {column}"
                
                pos += 1
                column += 1
                tokens.append({"type": "STRING", "value": res})
            elif currentChar in varChars:
                pos += 1
                column += 1

                res = currentChar

                while pos < length and src[pos] in varChars:
                    res += src[pos]

                    pos += 1
                    column += 1

                if res not in KEYWORDS:
                    tokens.append({"type": "VARIABLE_NAME", "value": res})
                elif res in KEYWORDS:
                    tokens.append({"type": "KEYWORD", "value": res})
            elif currentChar == "=":
                pos += 1
                column += 1
                tokens.append({"type": "OPERATOR", "value": currentChar})
            elif currentChar in integers:
                res = ""

                while pos < length and src[pos] in integers:
                    print(src[pos])
                    res += src[pos]

                    pos += 1
                    column += 1

                tokens.append({"type": "INTEGER", "value": res})
            elif currentChar == "(":
                pos += 1
                column += 1
                tokens.append({"type": "OPEN_PAREN", "value": currentChar})
            elif currentChar == ")":
                pos += 1
                column += 1
                tokens.append({"type": "CLOSE_PAREN", "value": currentChar})
            elif currentChar == ";":
                res = ""

                pos += 1
                column += 1

                while pos < length and src[pos] != "\n":
                    res += src[pos]

                    pos += 1
                    column += 1
                
                pos += 1
                column += 1
                tokens.append({"type": "COMMENT", "value": res})
            else:
                return [], f"Unexpected character {currentChar} at line {line}, column {column}"
```

P.S: pos is the current index in the src, and src is the code.

When i eventually reach the end of my parser it says that I'm missing a character, always being the character after the end of a number.

e.g:

```py
print(10)
```

in this code the closing parenthesis would be skipped over by the lexer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When while-loop is left, "pos" already points to the character after the number, so "pos" shouldn't be incremented again.

Comment: why don’t you put the whole code to help your more? Where is the first if condition?

Comment: Sure, I'll send that.

Comment: Here's my entire code:

Answer (score 0):

You're accidentally incrementing your position again outside of your loop.

```
     while pos < length and src[pos] in integers:
            print(src[pos])
            res += src[pos]

            pos += 1
            column += 1
        
        pos += 1 # <-------------------
        column += 1 # <----------------
```

As your lexer enters it's last iteration of this loop, it reads the final digit, increments it's position, and then increments it again, thus skipping the character afterward.